# Remove duplicates in MySQL table - set group_id when city_id is the same

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table `units` in my database. In schema I have fields `id`, `unit_id`, `group_id`, `city_id`.

For simple I have 3 units:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2, 1)
(3, 1, 3, 2)
```

How can I remove useless groups id, when city id is the same. I have next result:

```
(1, 1, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 3, 2)
```

I know how do this in PHP, but I think 'maybe MySQL has inbuild functions which i don't know' ;)

Regards

Comment: How will MySQLi will know that value is useless group id you need php i think

Comment: What is the expected end result from the above 3 rows? Row 1 and 3? Do you want to keep the lowest id where the unit_id, group_id, and city_id are all the same (all 3 the same) or where the group_id and city_id (just those 2) are the same? Or the highest id? Please specify

Comment: Any code, table layout, etc available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, my solution:

```
UPDATE `ingame_units` INNER JOIN `ingame_groups` g1 ON `ingame_units`.`group_id`=g1.`id` LEFT JOIN `ingame_groups` g2 ON `ingame_units`.`group_id`<>g2.`id` AND g1.`city_id`=g2.`city_id` AND g1.`id`>g2.`id` AND g1.`game_id`=g2.`game_id` SET `ingame_units`.`group_id`=IFNULL(g2.`id`,g1.`id`)
```

Thanks one man to minus my post and don't try to help me. Regards :)

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly you want to all group_id have same value from the same city_id. Basically your first table in question is what you have and the second one is desired result. If that's the case your query could look like this:

```
UPDATE table1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY city_id) AS tx
ON table1.city_id = tx.city_id
SET table1.group_id = tx.group_id;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e8c8/2) to see how it's work.

If you want to completely remove values and to hold only distinct city_id then you can do that with query like this:

```
DELETE table1 FROM table1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table1 GROUP BY city_id) AS tx
ON table1.city_id = tx.city_id
WHERE table1.group_id != tx.group_id;
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1578d/1) for that!

In this case your result table will be without row with id 2...

GL!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to delete rows where `group_id` and `city_id` are equal? If so, it's very simple:

```
DELETE FROM units WHERE group_id = city_id
```

Comment: This is only simple code, from another way i don't think SQL has `==` operator. For simple group id it will be 3 and 130, and city id will be 13 - what i will do in this case?

Comment: Fixed the == typo. Can you post an example of what you're trying to achieve? What is the expected result?